# what happens when java builds the jar (war)

Tags: java, build, compilation

I'am new to maven and because of the scope properties I began to think about how java builds the jars (or wars). Let's say I write the source code for my project which will be compiled as myProject.jar. For my project I need one other jar the externalProject.jar. So I add externalProject.jar to my build path.

Question: When I compile my Project to get myProject.jar, will externalProject.jar included in myProject.jar, so that I can deliver only myProject.jar and it will run? Or is myProject.jar just calling code of externalProject.jar and exernalProject.jar must be in the same folder as myProject.jar and must be delivered too?

Helmsen

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on how you configure the dependencies in Maven.
Using a dependency scope "Runtime" for externalProject while configuring dependencies for myProject in its pom.xml file, indicates to the dependency management framework within Maven that it is not required for compilation, but is for execution.
Similarly using "compile" which is also the default scope, indicates that project be included in the classpath. So most likely you are using the "compile" default scope for the externalProjects dependency if you do not specify explicitly specify scope. In this scenario, your dependency will be included as a JAR for your project.

I would recommend reading the [Maven-Introuduction-To-Dependency-Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: Independant of maven: this is the difference between build path and class path? Jars in Build path will be "inside myProject.jar" and jars in the class path will must be provided?